# How to get key of an associative array by searching for offset value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key, associative-array

Using this as an example and being aware of [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php),

```
$arr = array(
    'product1'=>array('color'=>'blue','size'=>'medium'),
    'product2'=>array('color'=>'green','size'=>'large'),
    'product3'=>array('color'=>'yellow','size'=>'small'),
);
```

Is there a method for getting any key in multidimensional array by its incremented value?

For example, I'd like to get the key of the third array value in `$arr` above.  `$arr[2]` would return the value (an array containing yellow/small).

Is there a way to leverage the `key` function to get any key by its numeric iterator, rather than the key from the "current position"?

Or, is there another built-in function that I am obviously overlooking which would return the key of `$arr[2]` instead of it's value?

```
echo getkey($arr[2]);

# returns product3
```

Comment: You want to try array_map to achieve your solution

Comment: a coder  the answer you selected, is no where checked that based on given number any key exist or not. So it will give undefined index error in multiple cases.

Comment: To  whoever just downvoted this question:  If you're going to downvote at least post a comment explaining your action.  Don't hit and run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use array_keys function :

```
$arr = array(
            'product1'=>array('color'=>'blue','size'=>'medium'),
            'product2'=>array('color'=>'green','size'=>'large'),
            'product3'=>array('color'=>'yellow','size'=>'small'),
        );

$keys = array_keys($arr);

echo $keys[2];

// shorter version
echo array_keys($arr)[2];
```

More infos : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: this answer no where checked that based on given number any key exist or not. So it will give undefined index error in multiple cases.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem logical/efficient to generate a new/full array of keys just to select one from it.  The other answers are "working too hard".

`array_slice()` specifically extracts portions of an array based on position rather than key name.  This makes it the perfect function for this case.

Better practice would be to only slice away the subarray that you want, then call for its key, like this:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d89cfb9002da62d12f727ae4488f35aeb8833138))

```
$arr = array(
            'product1'=>array('color'=>'blue','size'=>'medium'),
            'product2'=>array('color'=>'green','size'=>'large'),
            'product3'=>array('color'=>'yellow','size'=>'small'),
        );
$key=2;
echo key(array_slice($arr,$key,1));  // [input],[0-indexed position],[number of subarrays]
```

Output:

```
product3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_keys()` function:

```
function getKey($arr, $i) {
    if (empty($arr[array_keys($arr)[$i]])) {
        return null;
    }

    // array_keys($arr)[$i] returns original array's key at i position
    // if i = 2, array_keys($arr)[$i] = 'product3'
    return array_keys($arr)[$i];
}

// echo getKey($arr, 2);
// returns product3
```